# Apparently agentive -r forms in Old Norse

Tags: verbs, germanic-languages, nouns, derivation, old-norse

I'm trying to understand forms like "Hræsvelgr" (Mythological creature; lit. corpse swallower) and "vínsvelgr" (Drunkard) in Old Norse.

The verb "svelga" is "to swallow", and thus in these forms it follows that this is an agentive and that it is a noun that does the swallowing, and adding another noun specifies what it swallows. However this doesn't make sense as -r doesn't appear to be an agentive.

In fact "svelgr" seems to be the second/third person singular present indicative of svelga, which is a verb, not a noun.

I understand that the default order of verbs in Old Norse was VO, so reanalysis seems unlikely.

Comment: _Svelgr_ by itself means both ‘maelstrom, whirlpool, eddy’ and ‘glutton’. It is derived from the same root as ‘swallow’, but it is not an agent noun; it’s from PG _*swalgiz_, a simple _i_-stem that also seems to have had a dual meaning: one relating to whirlpools or chasms, and one relating to the gullet or throat. But you’re right that the meaning does seem to be quite close to a traditional agent noun – but then a word describing the actor of an action needn’t necessarily be an agent noun specifically.